# Html canvas timing animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to make a circle move across the canvas, but when I use the `setInterval` method in my `draw` function it doesn't work. How would I go about doing this, would I have to redraw the object each time it moves?

Here is my code:

```
var cCoords = [0,0,20,0,2*Math.PI];
var sCoords = [];

function draw(){
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   setInterval(function(){circle(ctx)},3000)    
}
function circle(ctx){
    ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(cCoords[0],cCoords[1],cCoords[2],cCoords[3], cCoords[4]);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle="#FFFF33";
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
cCoords[0]++;
}
```

I'll add the clear function later, to clean up the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The function `draw()` is never called, and `canvas` and `ctx` are not available to parent scope.

`var ctx, canvas` must be defined outside that function. You can by moving the context to parent scope also simplify a little:

```
var cCoords = [0,0,20,0,2*Math.PI];
var sCoords = [];
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

circle();   // draw circle first time
setInterval(circle, 3000);

function circle(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cCoords[0],cCoords[1],cCoords[2],cCoords[3], cCoords[4]);
    ctx.closePath();   // must come before stroke()
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillStyle="#FFFF33";
    ctx.fill();
    cCoords[0]++;
}
```